# How to change frequency for the RSS Import Module

Tags: rss, frequency, pligg

I wish to find out if it is possible, and how I could change the frequency for the Pligg CMS in the RSS Import module from hours to minutes.

- Feed Frequency (hours): 12 -- how often to check for new items.

CMS Download: http://pligg.com/download/.
RSS Module Download: http://forums.pligg.com/99555-post17.html.

Answer (score 0):

on a quick glance, i see 2 possibilities:

a) modify the source. search all files for `feed_freq_hours`, change all occurrences to `feed_freq_minutes`, and fix all references (eg. instead of `$feed->feed_freq_hours * 3600`, you will have to use `$feed->feed_freq_minutes * 60`). you will also have to rename the `feed_freq_hours` column of the `[table_prefix]feeds` table. good luck!
b) (ab)use `feed_freq_hours` for minutely update frequencies by using fractional hours: eg. for an update every 10 minutes, enter `0.1666667` (a sixth of an hour). this will need a change of the `feed_freq_hours` column from `int` to `float`, eg. `ALTER TABLE [table_prefix]feeds CHANGE feed_freq_hours feed_freq_hours float`.

you might be better of submitting a feature request to the author.

Comment: sure i do. i'm just not available for consulting at the moment.

Comment: When will you be available to assist me with some help please?

Comment: feed_freq_hours column of the [table_prefix]feeds
I don't understand how to do this bit?

Comment: "[table_prefix]" means the table prefix you are using. if you don't use a table prefix, the table name is just "feeds"; if your table prefix is "pligg_", the table name is "pligg_feeds", etc. and you have to rename the "feed_freq_hours" column of that table to "feed_freq_minutes". is this clearer?